# How to grab the latest data via time stamp, grab the sum of one column, eliminate dups, then sum other columns

Tags: sql, hadoop, sum, duplicates

DBMS = Hadoop, Using Teradata SQL Assistant

How do I grab all the distinct records from this table based on max(tstamp), sum qty1, sumqty2 and THEN delete duplicates record based on time1,time2,time3,docnum1?

Or how can I do multiple queries and join them together? Like query1 will grab the sum values for qty1 and qty2 for unique docnums for each day. Query2 will remove duplicates based on time1,time2,time3,docnum1.Then join those two tables together on docnum1 and date?

This is the original table. There are 20 location values (c1). Each Location has a set of aisles (c2). Timestamp (c3) can have duplicates and max(tstamp) to grab the latest and greatest. DocNum1 (c4) is the new combined doc# & DocuNum2# (c5) is the old number. qty1 and qty2 are unique whereas time1, time2, time3

| Location | Aisle | Tstamp | DocNum1 | DocNum2 | qty1 | qty2 | time1 | time2 | time3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 420 | 4/16/2021 12:22:01 PM | 123 | 222 | 1 | 6 | 999 | 999 | 999 |
| 12 | 420 | 4/16/2021 11:22:01 PM | 123 | 123 | 5 | 3 | 999 | 999 | 999 |
| 12 | 420 | 4/16/2021 10:22:01 PM | 123 | 333 | 6 | 7 | 999 | 999 | 999 |
| 31 | 420 | 4/16/2021 12:22:01 AM | 666 | 444 | 6 | 7 | 999 | 999 | 999 |
| 31 | 120 | 4/16/2021 3:22:01 PM | 666 | 555 | 6 | 7 | 999 | 999 | 999 |
| 22 | 210 | 4/16/2021 01:22:01 PM | 666 | 666 | 999 | 999 | 999 | 999 | 999 |

I used this

```
with query1 AS
(
   SELECT *
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY location, aisle ORDER BY aisle, tstamp DESC) AS RowNum
   FROM   order_info
)
SELECT   location
       , aisle
       , DocNum1
       , DocNum2
       , Qty1
       , Qty2
       , time1
       , time2
       , time3
FROM   query1
JOIN date_db t2  ON to_date(tstamp) = t2.date_db
WHERE  RowNum = 1
AND t2.yearweek >= 202207
```

I dont know where to place the sums or how to integrate into this.

What I want to do is this:

| Location | Aisle | Tstamp | DocNum1 | DocNum2 | qty1 | qty2 | time1 | time2 | time3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 420 | 4/16/2021 12:22:01 PM | 123 | 222 | 12 | 16 | 999 | 999 | 999 |
| 31 | 420 | 4/16/2021 12:22:01 AM | 666 | 444 | 6 | 7 | 999 | 999 | 999 |
| 31 | 120 | 4/16/2021 3:22:01 PM | 666 | 555 | 6 | 7 | 999 | 999 | 999 |
| 22 | 210 | 4/16/2021 01:22:01 PM | 666 | 666 | 999 | 999 | 999 | 999 | 999 |

Comment: Add `sum(qty1) over (PARTITION BY location, aisle)` in query1 to calculate a *Group Sum* before filtering the 1st row

Comment: Runs and returns 0 results

Comment: That's impossible, the Group Sum is calculated in the same step as the Row_ Number, before filtering. Run a Select against the query1 without  join/where